# How can I use Moq's SetReturnsDefault method for classes?

Tags: .net-core, mocking, moq, xunit

After about an hour of struggling to get Moq's `SetReturnsDefault` method to work with my tests, I copied a test straight out of Moq's version 4 repository:

```cs
    // I didn't copy this part:
    public interface IFoo
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }

    // Just this part:
    [Fact]
    public void ReturnsDefaultValueOnProperty()
    {
        var mock = new Mock<IFoo>();
        mock.SetReturnsDefault(int.MinValue);

        Assert.Equal(int.MinValue, mock.Object.Value); 
        // Passes ✔
    }
```

Which works. However, when I swap out interface `IFoo` for class `Foo`, it fails:

```cs
    public class Foo
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }

    [Fact]
    public void ReturnsDefaultValueOnProperty()
    {
        var mock = new Mock<Foo>();
        mock.SetReturnsDefault(int.MinValue);

        Assert.Equal(int.MinValue, mock.Object.Value); 
        // ❌ Assert.Equal() Failure Expected: -2147483648 Actual: 0
    }
```

My guess is, when it uses the default constructor for `Foo`, `Value` is set to `default(int)`, which Moq must look at and decide that it doesn't need to use `SetReturnsDefault`'s default value? Most if not all the classes I am testing look something like `Foo`: how do I set defaults for properties in Moq without changing the classes themselves?

In particular, I'd like to set default string values for all `string` and `object` properties in my classes.

Comment: property needs to be `virtual` in order for Moq to be able to override its value.

Comment: Interesting, okay. If I'm dealing with non-virtual properties, is there a way to override default values on mocked class properties? Does Moq have that capability?

Comment: Moq is unable to work with non-overridden members members need to be either (virtual or abstract)

Comment: Is IFoo a dependency that does something, a service, repo etc, or a dto/model etc? Usually you don't mock the latter.

Comment: Yeah, it's just a model like I have in my example code. I was trying to be a good, lazy developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.

As Nkosi pointed out, **Moq** is only able to work with overridable members (`virtual` or `abstract`). I ended up instantiating my models per-test, which is what I should have done in the first place (I'm just lazy). If you really want to automatically assign values to your models without changing their structure, you might want to use reflection in a helper method that compares on the class property types to assign values:

```cs
foreach (var property in foo.GetType().GetProperties()) 
{
    if (property.PropertyType == typeof(string)) {
        property.SetValue(foo, "default value");
    }
    // etc...
}
```

It goes without saying, but if you go that route, keep it simple as possible to avoid introducing bugs into your test code.